# How to add a per element validation for en Enumerable in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-validation

I have this field that will be mapped from body:

```
[Required]
public IReadOnlyCollection<long?> Ids { get; set; }
```

I'd like to add a required attribute (or rather any arbitrary validation attribute) to the element itself (i.e. I want every element of the array validated).

I could create a class that would have an Id, but then I'll need to pass an array of objects from JSON while I'd like ideally to get an array like that `[1,2,3,4]`.

Is it possible to do with some trick, I did not manage to figure it out?

Comment: you could add something like this, [Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "At least one id is required")]]. Or you could write custom validator expanding ValidationAttribute attribute, also you have nullable, is null a valid value?

Comment: I can have such validation, but I think you misunderstood, I'll edit question to be more clear, I'd like validation per element

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute which will check for non nulls on an IEnumerable:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class NonNullElementsAttribute : ValidationAttribute{

 public override bool IsValid(object value)
 {
    // cast object to IEnumerable
    // Validate your logic.
 }
}
```

You can the put this property on top of your element

```
[Required]
[NonNullElements]
public IReadOnlyCollection<long?> Ids { get; set; }
```

You can make this even more generic by making it a more generic check on list that validates each element. For example for string types you may want string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know I can do this custom attribute and check what I need. I do though already have custom attributes operating on long and would rather reuse that logic.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik This not possible unfortunately and this complex scenario is the reason why many people move away from attributes and to solution like FluentValidation which can support those complex scenarios

Comment: Yes, I try to as much as possible stick to attributes, but I see the limitation. So I may be forced to switch to fluent...